# firebase.initializeApp (options requires a valid configuration object

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

Am new to React Native, am currently facing this below error. am trying to use facebook authentical with firebase. I have followed all the steps that i need to follow from firebase and developer.facebook page.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1kU5.png)

and the is my firebase.initializeApp below

> import RNFirebase from 'react-native-firebase' const
>   configurationOptions = {   debug: true } const firebase =
>   RNFirebase.initializeApp() export default firebase;

Comment: You must share code blocks. line 84 on main.js

Comment: You must also attach any images in the post and not a link. The reason is in case the site goes down other users need to know the context of the issue. Please edit the question.